# C initialize struct and access by pointer

Tags: c, arrays, struct, segmentation-fault

I am a little bit confused, it seemed to that my flow is right, but I am getting Seg. fault (line 15)

My struct in header:

```
typedef struct ringBuf_t {
    uint32_t data[BUF_CAPACITY];
    int head;
    int tail;
    uint32_t capacity;
} ringBuf_t;
```

and how I use it:

```
ringBuf_t *create() {
    ringBuf_t buf = {.capacity = BUF_CAPACITY, .head = 0, .tail = 0};

    return &buf;
}

int push(ringBuf_t *buf, uint32_t item) {
    if (buf->head + 1 == buf->tail) {
        return -1;
    }

    buf->data[buf->head] = item;
    buf->head = (buf->head + 1) % buf->capacity;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not post code with line numbers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In line 5 you create a local variable on the stack, and when the function return it address the scope ends and the object memory is free. Hence if you use that address later you got a seg-fault

Comment: Technically, the object memory is not `free`d, the object goes out of scope when function `create` returns, dereferencing it afterwards invokes undefined behavior, for example because you are reading invalid values and/or overwriting something else when writing to it.  Compilers should be stricter with obvious bugs like this and flag them as errors.

Comment: @chqrlie well that's the meaning of `freed` (I didn't write `deleted` on purpose)

Comment: @OhadEytan: Sorry for being picky, but this is C code, there is no `delete` operator. `free` has a very specific meaning, which does not cover the OP's problem. Dereferencing `free`d memory invokes undefined behavior as well, but in the above code `buf` has just gone out of scope.

Comment: @chqrlie the memory consider **free** to use and the actual data did not **deleted**. Those are words in english with relevant meaning except for the operator/function meaning.

Comment: @OhadEytan: did you mean *free* as in free beer or *free* as in free speech?  Using *free* in this context is at best confusing ;-)

Comment: @chqrlie _free_ as free for use to others (hence the program can use this memory for other information). I don't see the confusion, but maybe it's just me :)